# Rails: create through-record via association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

If anyone has a better title, please let me know :p

I have the following models:

```
class Car
  has_many :car_drivers
  has_many :drivers, :through => :car_drivers
end

class Driver
  has_many :car_drivers
  has_many :cars, :through => :car_drivers
end

class CarDriver
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :driver
end
```

Now I want to create a new Driver via Car, but the record in the join-table (car_drivers) should be created as well. I tried the following, but while the car record is created, the join-table record is not: `driver_object.cars.create`

What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following is going to create new instance of `Car`, but does not associate it with the `Driver` instance.

```
driver_object.cars.create
```

The following works

```
driver_object.cars << Car.create(...)
```

The `<<` method in ActiveRecord appends the newly created `Car` instance to the `:cars` collection on `Driver` **and** calls `save` on `Driver`, creating the `CarDriver` instance to relate the new `Car` with `driver_object`.

Comment: @deefour  How do we add values to the CarDriver model if they have more attributes? I mean what is the best practice