# rails 4 no data is being transferred to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do user reviews, when user can write review to another user, i create tables review with :content, user_reviews with :for_user_id, and by_user_id,
my routes

```
devise_for :users
  resources :users, :only => [:show] do
    resources :reviews
  end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :users, :through => :users_reviews
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users_review
  has_many :reviews, :through => :users_review
end

class UsersReview < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :review
end

class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @review = @user.reviews.new(params[:for_user_id])
    end

    def create
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    def show
    end

    def index
        @user = User.find(params[:for_user_id])
        @reviews = Review.all
    end

    private
    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:user_id, :user_id, :content)
    end

end
```

and my view

```
<%= form_for([@user, @user.reviews.build]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Your review" %>
<%= f.submit "Go", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

all work, but no data send to the db :\ what i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're not saving anything in the `create` method, therefore nothing is going to persist.

You'll want something like:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @review = @user.reviews.build(review_params)

  if @user.save && @review.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    (handle bad data)
  end
end
```

I would also tend to agree with @marzapower - If you want to use `current_user`, you don't need the line above `@review`.  My method above has this change included.

Comment: yep, i found this mistake, but when i fix that, rails send data to the review table, and dont send data to the users_review... users_review is empty

Comment: See my edit.  You'll want to do `@user.save` to create the association.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654040/rails-create-through-record-via-association

Comment: Since he's using `<%= form_for([@user, @user.reviews.build]) do |f| %>` with a specific user, I doubt the real target is `current_user`. It would be a misuse of nested resources routes.

Comment: @marzapower - totally agree!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a call to the `save` method in your `create` action:

```
def create
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     @review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)
     @review.save
     redirect_to root_path
end
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403671/the-differences-between-build-create-and-create-and-when-should-they-be-us) explains the difference between build and create.

Comment: yep, i found this mistake, but when i fix that, rails send data to the review table, and dont send data to the users_review... users_review is empty

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing two things.  The User and Review classes both need to reference the UserReview class that they employ in the through relationship, e.g.,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :user_reviews_received, class_name: 'UserReview', foreign_key: :for_user_id
  has_many :reviews_received, through: :user_reviews_received, class_name: 'Review'

  has_many :user_reviews_written,  class_name: 'UserReview', foreign_key: :by_user_id
  has_many :reviews_written, through: :user_reviews_written, class_name: 'Review'
  ...
end
```

As noted above, the create action seems a bit confused.  Generally speaking the params should be the same for building up an instance in the new and create actions but you've got some differences.  You could resolve this in one of two ways.  One option would be to resolve it in the controller.

```
class ReviewsController < ActionController::Base
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @review = @user.reviews_received.new(by_user_id: current_user.id)
  end

  def create
    @review = @user.reviews_received.create(params[:review].merge(by_user_id: current_user.id))
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

The second option would be to resolve it in the view (new first line in the form).

```
<%= form_for([@user, @user.reviews_received.build(by_user_id: current_user.id)]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :by_user_id %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Your review" %>
  <%= f.submit "Go", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I would tend towards something like the first option

Comment: thanks, but now rails give error ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ReviewsController#create unknown attribute: for_user_id @review = @user.reviews.create(params[:review].merge(for_user_id: params[:for_user_id])) i thinks all my problems are in the db, in table users_review with for_user_id, and by_user_id

Comment: I could only infer so much from your post so I simply tried to get the new and create actions to agree.  If you have by_user_id and for_user_id in the Review model then let's update the User model to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the controller, I think:

```
def create
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @review = @user.reviews.build(review_params)
    @review.save
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

You were creating new `Review`s for `current_user` instead of `@user`.

Comment: I missed to include the `save` method, my bad. Answer updated.

Comment: it works, but rails dont send data into join table, users_review

Comment: What do the other tables contain?